# Extract line that matches with my criteria in Python

Tags: python

I have a variable with this inside:

> **Device ID: second-02** Entry address(es):   **IP address: 7.7.7.7**
>   Platform: cisco WS-8PC-S,  Capabilities: Router Switch IGMP Interface:
>   GigabitEthernet0/20,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/11
>   Holdtime : 100 sec
>    Power request id: 0, Power management id: 1, Power available: 0, Power management level: -1 Management address(es):   **IP address:
>   7.7.7.7**
>
> **Device ID: first-01** Entry address(es):   **IP address: 8.8.8.8** Platform:
>   cisco ME--12CS-A,  Capabilities: Router Switch IGMP Interface:
>   GigabitEthernet0/11,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/12
>   Holdtime : 158 sec  Power request id: 0, Power management id: 0, Power available: 0, Power management level: 0 Management address(es):  **IP address: 8.8.8.8**

How can I extract each **IP address** with its respective **Device ID** and output something like

> **Device ID: second-02 = IP address: 7.7.7.7**
>
> **Device ID: first-01 = IP address: 8.8.8.8**

Please note that for each **Device ID** we have one unique **IP address** but each one appears two times inside the main variable

So far Ive been able to verify if there is an **IP address** inside the variable  with `ip = re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', s )` but that wont do the trick as I need each **Device ID** to be paired (or matched?) against its **IP address**.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Just how is that information stored in the variable? Is all that highlighted information just one string, is it a list or tuple with two items, is it a dictionary, or something else? Since you are using `re` you probably mean one string, but that certainly does not look like a string, especially with highlighted sections and multiple paragraphs. Please print the `repr()` of your variable.

Comment: it is a <type 'str'> [here](https://regex101.com/r/BsIRh1/3) it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using this regular expression: 
`r'Device ID: ([^ ]*) Entry address\(es\): IP address: ([^ ]*)'`

https://regex101.com/r/BsIRh1/2

Comment: This is almost there but the regular expression that I get from [here](https://regex101.com/r/BsIRh1/3) doesnt work in python (i guess because it has an "enter" )

Comment: Use the escape sequence for enter characters then.
https://regex101.com/r/BsIRh1/5